# Why discard is not allowed in expression tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I found such report about forbidding discards in expression trees: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20380 and indeed they are not allowed. But I wonder -- **why**?

After all all it takes to avoid this error is introducing dummy variable, passing it as `out` argument and that's all. So exactly the same pattern of manually discarding `out` as before introduction of discard.

So why expression trees are so special, that discard cannot be used there?